# Roles based authorization in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and want to understand the authentication mechanism in MVC

I have these tables in SQL, Users table, Roles table and UserRoles table which maps user id column to role id column. Now as soon as I add an attribute Authorize(Roles = "Customer") I want the access to be given only to the users having customer priviliges. Now what is is that I have to do to create a link between these two. I am looking for a step by step explanation or a link which points me to do this exactly, as I found a number of articles googling out on this and was unable to find the matching one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the out of the box MVC template, you don't need to do anything to enforce this behavior. A database will be created for you as soon as you launch your application with a number of tables (Users, roles, mapping between users and roles, ...). Check your web.config for the connection string.

The only thing for you to do is to populate the ROLES table and then match those entries with the Authorize attribute in code. So if you have a role named "Admin" in the database, you can protect your actions and controllers with following code:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
```

You could also take it further to limit access by users but I wouldn't consider that as a best practice. Next, create a user in the UI and then match this user to a role you specified in the DB. Login as this user and you'll notice you have access to the restricted action/controller.

For more information, he best articles are those from Microsoft themselves, like [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) one.